# Как разделить слишком длинное сообщение Telegram-бота на несколько коротких?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, текст

Всем привет! Проблема такова: пишу простенького Telegram-бота, который выдаёт интересные упражнения по выбору со встроенной кливиатуры. Но дело в том, что текст сообщений с упражнениями зачастую превышает лимит в 4096 знаков. Искал, гуглил, пытался перестроить найденные варианты под свой код, но ничего не выходит. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете решить проблему.

Вот, собственно, код для выдачи рандомного варианта из списка упражнений по нажатию на клавишу ' Память'.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def exercise(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Память':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Другое упражнение", callback_data='memory_another')
            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.choice(memory_tasks)), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Можно попробовать разделить сообщение по 4096 символов и отправить несколькими сообщениями. Либо сделать одним сообщением, но добавить inline-кнопки для переключения между кусками сообщения. Первый вариант проще

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243478/Оптимизация-кода-python-бот-на-pytelegrambotapi-и-решение-ошибки-связанной-с-с

Я нашёл вот такой вариант, но никак не допру, как применять в моём случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Определил переменную `MESS_MAX_LENGTH`
- Отправку сделал через цикл (прелесть в том, что если сообщение и будет меньше `MESS_MAX_LENGTH`, то все-равно код цикла выполнится)

Пример:

```
MESS_MAX_LENGTH = 4096

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def exercise(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Память':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Другое упражнение", callback_data='memory_another')
            markup.add(item1)

            text = str(random.choice(memory_tasks))
            for x in range(0, len(text), MESS_MAX_LENGTH):
                mess = text[x: x + MESS_MAX_LENGTH]
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает!

Comment: @СергейАрлов, пожалуйста :)

Comment: @ gil9red, здравствуйте, у меня та же проблема с одним но, мне нельзя делить сообщения используя жестко определенный шаг(MESS_MAX_LENGTH), мое сообщение в телеграм формируется из нескольких шаблонных сообщений, которые нельзя делить, т.е. можно определить плавающее значение шага? Может быть внутри цикла считать len(text) и когда колличество символов в сообщении < MESS_MAX_LENGTH то выводить его и начинать считать дальше... не хватает опыта в решении этого вопроса. Помоги пожайлуйста.

Comment: @DjonyCooper, добрый день, задайте отдельный вопрос по вашей проблеме. Если приведете пример шаблонов текста и как их хотелось бы делить, то ответ получите быстрее - т.к. будет больше желающих помочь :)